# How to pass a custom build property to csproj?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, csproj

How to pass custom build properties to csproj file ? My csproj is upgraded from VS2008 to VS2012.

Under MSBuild3, the build runs fine. I am able to access the custom properties. However, under on MSBuild4, I have the following warning.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:MyCustomProp=WHATEVER' will be ignored. [C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:MyCustomPropTwo=WHATEVERTWO' will be ignored. [C:\src\MyProj\MyProj.csproj]
```

I am running this build under MSBuild 4 using script written in VS2008.

Comment: Have you defined your property in the csproj file?

Comment: pm_2, how to define a property in csproj file ? Example please ?

Comment: You do mean compiler properties?

Comment: Yes, the custom build properties used by the MSbuild process. It can be used by compiler and/or linker.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a custom property to the msbuild commandline use the /p:PropertyName=PropertyValue command switch, this can be used multiple times. The PropertyName is then available within your msbuild script as $(PropertyName). See [msbuild commandline reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

CSharp.targets file is an msbuild file, so you will have to lookup, which properties you want to pass.